# Can't remove value in brackets and update value

Tags: php, laravel

I get a list of the items from the CS:GO game by API. The item name is as follows for example: `AUG | Syd Mead (Well-Worn)`, when parsing I try to remove this: `(Well-Worn)`, I have the code, but it doesn't update information and doesn't remove value with brackets.

Example of API result:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "currency": "USD",
    "timestamp": 1608675023,
    "items_list": {
                 },
        "1st Lieutenant Farlow | SWAT": {
            "name": "1st Lieutenant Farlow | SWAT",
            "rarity": "Superior",
            "rarity_color": "d32ce6",
            "price": {
                "24_hours": {
                    "average": 2.45,
                    "median": 2.45,
                    "sold": "444",
                    "standard_deviation": "3.41",
                    "lowest_price": 2.37,
                    "highest_price": 2.63
                },
             }
        },
        "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)": {
            "name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
            "exterior": "Battle-Scarred",
            "rarity": "Covert",
            "rarity_color": "eb4b4b",
            "price": {
                "7_days": {
                    "average": 15.48,
                    "median": 15.39,
                    "sold": "299",
                    "standard_deviation": "5.17",
                    "lowest_price": 11.2,
                    "highest_price": 17.36
                },
            },
        }
```

How you can see, the first item doesn't have `exterior`, the second item has `exterior` on response.

My function with update all information what I need:

```
public function update_information()
{
    $prices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/?prettyprint=true'), true);

    if (!$prices['success']) {
        dd('Error');
    }

    $newPrices = [];
    $newColor = [];

    foreach ($prices['items_list'] as $price) {
        $newPrices[$price['name']] = $price['rarity'];
        $newColor[$price['name']] = $price['rarity_color'];
    }

    $totalUpdated = 0;

    foreach (AllItem::query()->get() as $itemDB) {
        $fullName = $itemDB->market_hash_name;
        $newName = trim(str_replace('('.$itemDB->exterior.')', '', $fullName));

        if (!isset($newPrices[$fullName])) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isset($newColor[$fullName])) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isset($newName)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isset($itemDB->exterior)) {
            continue;
        }

        $itemDB->update(['market_hash_name' => $newName]);
        $itemDB->update(['exterior' => $newPrices[$fullName]]);
        $itemDB->update(['rarity' => $newPrices[$fullName]]);
        $itemDB->update(['rarity_color' => $newColor[$fullName]]);
        $totalUpdated++;
    }

    dd('done. Updated images: ' . $totalUpdated);
}
```

In `foreach` I have variable `$newName` which need to make `str_replace` and function `->update`, which needs to update the database, but it doesn't work.

Also I try change to:

```
 if(!empty($itemDB->exterion)) {
        $newName = str_replace('('.$itemDB->exterior.')', '', $fullName);
 }
```

`empty($itemDB->exterion)` because some items don't has exterior (in example we can see it). But I received 0 updates in my table :(

Where is my mistake? Maybe `$newName` variable is wrong? How I can remove brackets and make update in the database?

Comment: AllItem::query()->get() return something?

Comment: yes, sure, i get all items in my table received from API

Comment: I think you should see sql query from `updating` eloquent by using `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`. Could you please share the output?